# Dataset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset

I have a large set of cross-sectional time series data in a dataset in Matlab and I want to extract arrays (columns) of data based on the header which will be given dynamically from another array in for loop. Can anyone suggest how to implement this in Matlab, I have tried the following code

```
cdslist = universe.Bond;
cdscount = length(universe.Bond);

for i=1:cdscount
    cds = cdslist(i);
% here i want to use this variable cds to dynamically give names to a dataset called spread, for instance spread.cds where cds is changing in the loop. 

end
```

Is this possible ? 
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `cds` is a string, it can be used as a dynamic field name:

```
cdslist = universe.Bond;
cdscount = length(universe.Bond);

spread = struct;

for i = 1:cdscount
    cds = cdslist{i};
    spread.(cds) = data;
end
```

Comment: you can even do without the `cds`, just use: `spread.(cdslist(i))`

Comment: can you clarify what is data ?

Comment: thing is spread already exists as a dataset with cross-sectional data and i want to extract data from it for a security name say "X" given by cdslist

Comment: `data` was just an example of assigning to the struct. What is the data structure of `spread`? Is "X" one of the elements? If you give an example of your data sets and the intended outcome then I might be able to help.

Comment: thanks, I just have one more doubt. the cds is in 1x1 cell format. how can i convert it into string ?

Comment: If `cdslist` is a cell, then `cds = cdslist{i}` returns a string.